# Angular Node.js CPanel Deployment

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, cpanel, angular-universal

I am trying to deploy my Angular Universal using Node.js option in CPanel. My configuration is as follows:

```
Node.js Version: 12.9.0
Application Mode: Development
Application Root: public_html/ssr
Application URL: ssr
Application Startup File: main.js
```

It has managed to run `npm install` and node_modules are now installed. But when I press '`RUN JS SCRIPT`' it gives me an error. Following is the log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/opt/alt/alt-nodejs11/root/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/opt/alt/alt-nodejs11/root/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run-script',
1 verbose cli   'build',
1 verbose cli   '--' ]
2 info using npm@6.7.0
3 info using node@v11.15.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle sunnyssr@0.0.0~prebuild: sunnyssr@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle sunnyssr@0.0.0~build: sunnyssr@0.0.0
7 warn lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /home/sunnytex/nodevenv/public_html/ssr/11/bin/node but npm is using /opt/alt/alt-nodejs11/root/usr/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
8 verbose lifecycle sunnyssr@0.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle sunnyssr@0.0.0~build: PATH: /opt/alt/alt-nodejs11/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/sunnytex/public_html/ssr/node_modules/.bin:/home/sunnytex/nodevenv/public_html/ssr/11/bin:/opt/alt/alt-nodejs11/root/usr/bin:/home/sunnytex/nodevenv/public_html/ssr/11/lib/bin/:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin:/opt/bin
10 verbose lifecycle sunnyssr@0.0.0~build: CWD: /home/sunnytex/public_html/ssr
11 silly lifecycle sunnyssr@0.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'ng build' ]
12 info lifecycle sunnyssr@0.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: sunnyssr@0.0.0 build: `ng build`
13 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/alt/alt-nodejs11/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:999:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:266:5)
14 verbose pkgid sunnyssr@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/sunnytex/public_html/ssr
16 verbose Linux 2.6.32-954.3.5.lve1.4.76.el6.x86_64
17 verbose argv "/opt/alt/alt-nodejs11/root/usr/bin/node" "/opt/alt/alt-nodejs11/root/usr/bin/npm" "run-script" "build" "--"
18 verbose node v11.15.0
19 verbose npm  v6.7.0
20 error file sh
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno ENOENT
23 error syscall spawn
24 error sunnyssr@0.0.0 build: `ng build`
24 error spawn ENOENT
25 error Failed at the sunnyssr@0.0.0 build script.
25 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
26 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My package.json is as follows

```
{
  "name": "sunnyssr",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run sunnyssr:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/sunnyssr/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run sunnyssr:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run sunnyssr:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^10.0.1",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "ngx-image-zoom": "^0.6.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-page-scroll": "^7.0.1",
    "ngx-page-scroll-core": "^7.0.1",
    "node": "^10.21.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.4",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^10.0.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

I would be grateful if someone could kindly guide me how to fix this issue. Thank in advance.

Comment: But the local ng build doesn't fail?

Comment: @JohnPeters no on local it works perfectly fine. I have also added my package.json in the question if that might help